# How to call threadsafe rrd_update_r Round Robin Database function with C API?

Tags: c, thread-safety, rrdtool, rrd

Can anybody help me to find out how to call rrd_update_r function of the rrdtool c API from http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/index.en.html?

It was quite easy to call the non-threadsafe version of rrd_update, but this one is more tricky...

normal rrd_update:

```
  char *updateparams[] = {
        "rrdupdate",
        rrd_file,
        values,
        NULL
    };

    rrd_clear_error();
    result = rrd_update(3, updateparams); //argc is first arg
```

Because the programm has to run in a multithreaded environment I got several errors by not using the threadsafe functions!
But it is not so easy to use rrd_update_r, because it requires a template too...

```
 int    rrd_update_r(const char *filename, const char *_template,
            int argc, const char **argv);
```

and I really have no idea how to create one...

```
    char *updateparams[] = {
        "rrdupdate",
        rrd_file,
        values,
        NULL
    };


    rrd_clear_error();
   result = rrd_update_r(rrd_file, NULL,3, updateparams);
```

does not work and produces the following error when executing it...

```
error: /var/tmp/rrds/1.rrd: expected timestamp not found in data source from rrdupdate
```

Hopefully someone can help me!

thx and br,
roegi

Comment: I guess you took a look at http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/prog/rrdthreads.en.html ? Unfortunately, it doesn't mention `rrd_update_r`.

Comment: Yes I took a look at rrdthreads.en.html, but rrd_update_r is mentioned there as a reference implementation to look at(
"See rrd_update_r as an example").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working!
Nemo - thx for your help!
It was not exactly your solution but it was a hint to the right direction!

It works with:

```
/*
rrd_file is a char * to "/var/tmp/1.rrd"
NULL says not to use a template
1 --> argc 
values is a char * to "N:value-1:value-2:.....:value-n"
*/

result = rrd_update_r(rrd_file, NULL, 1, (void *) &values);
```

Comment: the queue_thread_main function in this example uses rrd_update_r http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool-trac/browser/trunk/program/src/rrd_daemon.c

Answer (score 1):

Well, looking at the source code...

It appears that `rrd_update_r` does not want to see the `"rrupdate"` argument.  So try just passing `rrd_file` and `values` as a 2-element `argv`.

Actually the source for `rrd_update` is not hard to read; you can find it in src/rrd_update.c.  And `rrd_update_r` appears to be a much lower-level function that `rrd_update` itself calls.  So this may not actually fix your underlying problem.

Comment: So you mean just to use a char * updateparams[] = {
        rrd_file,
        values,
        NULL
    };
as 4th argument?

Additionally a template seems to be required here as 2nd arg, but I have no clue what that should be and how to create it...

On the rrdtool website there is always mentioned that _r functions are the threadsafe ones and that rrd_update is already implemted in rrd_update_r in a threadsafe way - so hopefully it was really done...

Comment: @roegi: As far as I can tell, the `template` parameter can be NULL.  (Indeed, this is how `rrd_update` invokes `rrd_update_r` when the argv contains no `--template` argument.)

Comment: ok that sounds great! I will try to execute it tomorrow morning again with rrd_update_r(rrd_file, NULL,2, updateparams); and char * updateparams[] = { rrd_file, values, NULL };

I think that the same error("expected timestamp not found in data source from rrdupdate") will occur - but hopefully you are right!